# Build failing on Azure - The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found

Tags: .net, azure

I set up a deployment through Azure to deploy using a GitHub action. The action is failing with the error:

> error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2 were not found. To resolve this, install the Developer Pack (SDK/Targeting Pack) for this framework version or retarget your application.

Here's the GitHub for the app if that helps: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet

This app runs just fine locally. I've selected .NET 7 when setting it up in Azure, as well as with my app locally. Is there something else I need to configure beyond the steps I follow to create the application and deployment setup in Azure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you need to use *actions/setup-dotnet@v3* instead of *actions/setup-dotnet@v1* and do a restore before going to the build step.

**EDIT:** Also you need to specify the project or else it will build all of them including the UI project which is the one throwing the error.

```
- name: Set up .NET Core
    uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v2
    with:
      dotnet-version: '7.x'
      include-prerelease: true

  - name: Install dependencies
    run: dotnet restore

  - name: Build with dotnet
    run: dotnet build --configuration Release ./rardk.web.API/rardk.web.API.csproj 

  - name: dotnet publish
    run: dotnet publish  ./rardk.web.API/rardk.web.API.csproj -c Release -o ${{env.DOTNET_ROOT}}/myapp
```

Comment: I've run this update but I'm still getting the same error. Updated here: https://github.com/rarDevelopment/rardk-web-dotnet/blob/78d0ec82114cb73d13e90b25d0375d0119e1922e/.github/workflows/main_rardkweb.yml#L25

Error message is the same.

Comment: @muttley91 I have edited the answer with the required changes

Comment: @Skulad I'm trying to figure out if there's an issue with the path, I've updated with the above but I'm getting this error: `MSBUILD : error MSB1009: Project file does not exist.
Switch: ..rardk.web.APIrardk.web.API.csproj`

Comment: It means the path is wrong, try `dotnet build --configuration Release rardk.web.API.csproj` or `dotnet build --configuration Release ./rardk.web.API/rardk.web.API.csproj` using forward slashes since you are using ubuntu in the pipeline

Comment: okay nice yeah looks like that did the trick there. I'm still getting a not found on my deployment, but I'm not sure that's related at this point. https://rardkweb.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: Unrelated -That is because it is not matching the route, try [https://rardkweb.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast](https://rardkweb.azurewebsites.net/WeatherForecast)

Comment: ahh, that makes sense. so is there a way to publish the UI app in the same project, possibly to the root URL?